Password protected on compressed Zipped folder using dotnetzip library
I am trying to add a password using DotNetZip, but it's setting the password on the individual files inside the compressed folder, not on the main compressed folder itself. Could you suggest a free library that helps in this case?
Which library which is open source which can provide password on protected on folder level inside zipped file
(Zip File zip = new Zip File())
{
    zip. Password = password;
    zip. Add Directory (folder To Zip);
    zip. Save(zip File Path);

    Console. WriteLine("Folder successfully zipped and password protected.");
}


SharpZipLib maybe? Try on [softwarerecs.se]

I tried even this is same as dotnetzib
